# equivalent of pgcc "-Minfo=" flag for gcc compiler?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, pgcc

I just discovered the nice "-Minfo=" flag in pgcc, which outputs all the optimizations that the compiler is making.

IE:

```
pgcc -c -pg -O3 -Minfo=all -Minline    -c -o example.o example.c
run:
 55, Memory zero idiom, loop replaced by call to __c_mzero8
 91, Memory zero idiom, loop replaced by call to __c_mzero8
pgcc -c -pg -O3 -Minfo=all -Minline    -c -o controller.o controller.c
main:
 82, second inlined, size=4, file controller.c (113)
 84, second inlined, size=4, file controller.c (113)
```

is there an equivalent compiler flag for GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes there is**. `-fopt-info` is what you are looking for.

```
gcc -O3 -fopt-info example.c -o example
```

Or equivalently you can do

```
gcc -O3 -fopt-info-all=all.dat example.c -o example
```

Will output all the optimization information to file `all.dat`. You can also be specific about which optimization information you want by specifying `-fopt-info-options` like so:

```
-fopt-info-loop                 # info about all loop optimizations  
-fopt-info-vec                  # info about auto-vectorization
-fopt-info-inline               # info about function inlining
-fopt-info-ipa                  # info about all interprocedural optimizations
```

You can get more specific if you want by telling `gcc` to dump information only about `loops/inlinings/vectorizations` that were optimized or were missed

```
-fopt-info-inline-optimized     # info only about functions that were inlined
-fopt-info-vec-missed           # info only about vectorizations that were missed
-fopt-info-loop-note            # verbose info about loop optimization
```

For more details look at the [online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).